# GWT Get rid of the tables

Tags: gwt

I've inherited a GWT project that uses Panels and Panels beyond belief, all of which generated tons of nested tables. I want to style this program and to do so, I'd like to have all of my elements become `<div>`'s so I can CSS style them properly -- can someone tell me how to go about doing that? Are there widgets in GWT that don't use tables, etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Googling for [gwt panels] I found [this page](http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Panels~Summary) which lists which panels are backed by tables and which are backed by divs.  You should start by eliminating panels which are purely holding other panels, or nothing at all.  Then, if you can, refactor panels that use tables to ones that use divs.

Comment: As might not be immediately obvious from that great link, FlowPanel is just a regular <div> and as such should be the first panel you think of using, just like <div> should be the first block-level HTML element to consider.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the div based widgets such as FlowPanels and do your layout in css if you want to avoid tables. It works well for me. use getElement.setId() for setting the id of your panel.